# How can I display arrays one value in Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created an array and I want to display the array's value `opens` and `closes` to the view.

Shop class:

```
public function jsonLDFields()
{
    return $this->hasOne(JsonLDFields::class);
}
```

JsonLDFields class:

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

A shop has `jsonLDFields`, `jsonLDFields` has a DB column `value` for `store_opens` / `store_closes`

```
store_opens[store_times][monday][opens]

"store_opens" => array:1 [▼
    "store_times" => array:7 [▼
      "Monday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "09:00"
      ]
      "Tuesday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "09:00"
      ]
      "Wednesday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "09:00"
      ]
      "Thursday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "09:00"
      ]
      "Friday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "09:00"
      ]
      "Saturday" => array:1 [▼
        "closes" => "10:00"
      ]
      "Sunday" => array:1 [▼
        "opens" => "10:00"
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

When I try to display it like this:

`$shop->jsonLDFields->store_closes`.

The result is all arrays values.

When I try to display it like this:

`$shop->jsonLDFields->store_closes['opens']`

The result is null.

When I try to display it like this:

```
$shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens['store_times']['Monday']['opens']
```

The result is null.

When I do `dd($shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens);`

I get:

```
 array:1 [▼
 "store_times" => array:7 [▼
 "Monday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "09:00"
]
"tuesday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "09:00"
]
"Wednesday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "09:00"
]
"Thursday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "09:00"
]
"Friday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "09:00"
]
"Saturday" => array:1 [▼
  "closes" => "10:00"
]
"Sunday" => array:1 [▼
  "opens" => "10:00"
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

How could I display the `opens` and `closes` values in the view?

Comment: What is `jsonLDFields` or `store_closes`?

Comment: A shop has jsonLDFields, jsonLDFields has a value of store_opens, store_closes

Comment: Update your question with ALL relevant code

Comment: My mistake. $shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens['store_times']['monday']['opens']
Displays nothing.

Comment: monday =/= Monday

Comment: This was not the problem. Edited the question.

Comment: What's the value of `dd($shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens);`?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @ViktorasssIT please check my answer and tell me if further help needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and was able to display arrays values to the view.

The `$shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens` values was stored in `json array`, so I needed to fix this in the first place.

In Controller:

```
if(!$shop->jsonLDFields->store_times == null) {
        $shop->jsonLDFields->store_times = json_decode($shop->jsonLDFields- 
        >store_times);
    }
```

Then in the view:

```
$shop->jsonLDFields->store_opens->store_times->monday->opens.
```

There was no need for using foreach and e.t.c

Hope this helps someone, learnt a lot from this problem I had!